# Optimizing foreign key & manytomany field in REST API query

Tags: rest, api, django-rest-framework

I'm wondering is there anyway to optimize an api when using foreign key and ManytoMany field, for example :

Serializer :

```
class SerializerA(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Model_A
        fields = ('id', 'official_name', 'gender')
        depth = 1

class SerializerB(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    user = SerializerA(many=True)
    class Meta:
        model = Model_B
        fields = ('id', 'project_name','project_type', 'project_start_date', 'user')
        depth = 1
```

API :

```
class ReportAPI(APIView):
    def get(self, request):
        all_projects = Model_B.objects.all()
        project_serializer = SerializerB(all_projects, many=True)
        return Response(project_serializer.data)
```

now with this, if i go to the API url, and debug this page, it''l show that I'm querying 78 times from the SQL query. But if I remove one field from manytoMany seriealizer field which the `'gender'`, the page now will only query from the database 21 times, so my question is again, how can I optimize this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `select_related` (for ForeignKey) and/or `prefetch_related` (For ManyToMany or ManyToOne) so that it will not hit the database for each `Model_B` object.

If `user` is a FK in `Model_B` then you can do:

```
class ReportAPI(APIView):
    def get(self, request):
        all_projects = Model_B.objects.all().select_related('user')
        project_serializer = SerializerB(all_projects, many=True)
        return Response(project_serializer.data)
```

If the user model has other FK that you need in it's serializer, then you can also do `select_related('user', 'user__other_field')`.

Comment: Thank you so much for the help @Gabriel, my query drop from 78 to 10 after utilizing this, thanks again!!